# getting php json answer using ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm working data sent from PHP to ajax as JSON, but I'm having an heck of problems to access data. I've tried so many ways and none of them seems to work.

JSON:

```
{ 
   "_class":"course",
   "id":2,
   "title":"The Big Title",
   "url":"/my-slug-url/",
   "price":"$99.99",
   "headline":"A great description"
}
```

My Call:

```
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'url',
            data: {
                action: 'my_call',
                value: url
            },

            success: function(data) {
```

I want to get the price. I've tried `data[4].price` (since it's the 5th element of JSON), `data.price` and even `data[0].price` (since there's not multiple "id's").

I'm googling and I thought I've tried everything... But I'm sure I'm wrong.
Info from PHP comes from json_encode.

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` in your success-callback and see what the response actually looks like. Beats guessing :-)

Comment: `data.price` should be working. Try console.logging the raw responseText to check what's being returned if anything.

Comment: ATM i don't have console access to see the output, but I made and alert(data) and set the data value to a <p> tag and it outcomes the code above, but not prettyfied.

Comment: Can you try to add `header('Content-Type:application/json');` to your PHP file?

Comment: Do you see the above content if you do `alert(data)`? You should only see `object ojbect` since alerts can't output objects. If you add how you build and return the response in PHP, we might be able to guess what it looks like. Also show us the success-callback and how and where you're trying to get the `price`-property.

Comment: You don't have console access? You cannot press F12 on your browser?

Comment: I'm at work right now and ourselves blocked dev tools in internet access. Now I need it, but well... No problem :). Found the solution, will answer the thread for other that could need it.

Answer (score -1):

I've got it.
Let's say Ajax doesn't like to double json_encode. As I already sent data with `dataType: 'json'` I shouldn't in php do another `json_encode` before sent data. After remove `json_encode` from PHP, I can access with data.element (ex data.price).

Thanks to all.

Comment: Why would you json_encode the same data twice at all?

Comment: That was my error. I was getting a problem retrieving data and ended up with two encodes. One in Ajax call and other in PHP.